# Redirecting return value with dup2 from two different programs

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork, dup2

I've wrote two programs q & p to redirect the return value with dup2 from q to p.

I'm doing fork() in *"p"* and using execl to use *"q"* with child process that I'm creating. also I'm using dup2 to redirect the output of *"q"* to parent process in *"p"* to finally print it out.

I'm wondering why I can't see the output to the screen if I'm changing this line in *"q"* main: 
`printf("return value from q: %s\n", returnByte(argv, str));` to this line: `returnByte(argv, str);`

I'm new with this kind of programming, I'll appreciate any explanation.

q program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* returnByte(char* argv[], char* str);

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    char str[20];
    printf("return value from q: %s\n", returnByte(argv, str));

}

char* returnByte(char* argv[], char* str){
    float res = atof(argv[1])+atof(argv[2]);
    snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%.2f", res);
    return str;
}
```

p program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    float r[4];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){ 
        r[i] = (float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX/100); 
    }

    char arg1[10], arg2[10];
    snprintf(arg1, sizeof(arg1), "%.2f", r[0]);
    snprintf(arg2, sizeof(arg1), "%.2f", r[1]); 

    int pfd[2];
    pipe(pfd); //Creating a new pipe

    switch(fork()){ //fork()ing
        case -1: 
            printf("error occured during fork()ing");
            break;

        case 0: //Child process filling "q"'s job using dup2 & execl
            close(pfd[0]);
            dup2(pfd[1], 0);
            close(pfd[1]);
            execl("./q", "./q", arg1, arg2, NULL);          
            break;

        default: //Parent process display the output of q into the screen
            waitpid(-1, NULL, 0); //Wait until child process terminate (finish "q"'s job)
            close(pfd[1]);
            dup2(pfd[0], 1);
            close(pfd[0]);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `returnByte`, `sizeof(str)` returns 4 or 8, the size of your pointer. It's not what you want. I didn't look further.

Comment: The `default` branch makes no sense. You change stdout (`dup2(pfd[0], 1);`) and then exit without using stdout.

Comment: @ikegami what you mean? can you explain more specificly? waitpid i want to wait to child process to terminate, its not correct?

Comment: fd 1 is stdout, so `dup2(pfd[0], 1)` changes stdout. I have no idea why you do that. ( Ignore the bit about "Misplaced `waitpid`?". The answer to that is "no" :) )

Comment: @ikegami to print the output to the screen I guess... thats what our teacher taught us..

Comment: You get how `int a = 123;` is useless in `int a = 123; exit(0);`, right? So what's the point in changing stdout and exiting without using it (e.g. without printing anything to it)?

Comment: @ikegami can you suggest any correct way please? I'm still too newbie and must see some real code to undersatnd it better

Comment: Correct way to do what? All your question says is that they work fine. Twice. Even though they clearly don't. You didn't actually say what you want to do.

Comment: I was thinking that its work fine because my print out was correct until you said that it's not correct. now im running the code in my vmbox without default block and it print the same thing. didn't get the reason why...

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for bringing this to my attention, I've fixed it after reading the manual and reviewing again the examples from the last lecture :)!!!